# How to initialize helper method?

Tags: python

If I have two files helper.app and main.app, I want to be able to accomplish something like this.

helper.py

```
def configurestuff(dblocationstring):
  # Stuff that sets name and location
  generic_connection_variable = connectto(dblocationstring)

def dostuff():
  # does stuff with the generic_connection_variable
```

In my main.py, I want to be able to do something like

```
import helper
helper.configure("customlocationofdb")
helper.dostuff()
#or even
helper.generic_connection_variable.someApplicableMethod()
```

My goal is so that I can have a main.app that is able to use the "helper" passing variables to setup a connection and reuse that variable if possible within main.app after importing the helper. What is the best way to organize my code to accomplish this? (im not sure how to access generic_connection_variable in my main.py as it is in a function, or what the best way to do this is)

Comment: looks like factory method. maybe you can refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8129018/factory-method-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing this as a class allows for greater flexibility:

```
class Config(object):
    DB_STRING = 'some default value'
    ANOTHER_SETTING = 'another default'
    DEBUG = True

    def dostuff(self):
      print 'I did stuff to ',self.DEBUG

class ProductionConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = False # only turn of debugging

class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    DB_STRING = 'localhost'

    def dostuff(self):
       print 'Warning! Development system ',self.DEBUG
```

Store this in any file for example, `settings.py`. In your code:

```
from settings import Config as settings
# or from settings import ProductionConfig as settings

print settings.DEBUG # for example
```

Comment: Assume "generic_connection_variable" is an object that takes a string parameter for connection, in this case dblocationstring/DB_STRING.

Answer (score 1):

You can define `generic_connection_variable` to be a module level variable.

So in your `helper.py` you will have to

```
generic_connection_variable = None  # or whatever default you want.


def configurestuff(dblocationstring):
    global generic_connection_variable
    # Stuff that sets name and location
    generic_connection_variable = connectto(dblocationstring)

def dostuff():
    global generic_connection_variable
    # does stuff with the generic_connection_variable
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to tell what you are asking, but have you tried making `generic_connection_variable` an instance variable of `helper`? (with the `self` keyword)

`# helper.py:`

```
def configurestuff(dblocationstring):
  # Stuff that sets name and location
  self.generic_connection_variable = connectto(dblocationstring)
```

Now that `generic_connection_variable` belongs to an instance of `helper` instead of being local-scoped to `configurestuff`, you will be able to use it in `main` as follows:

```
import helper
helper.configure("customlocationofdb")
helper.generic_connection_variable.someApplicableMethod()
```

But you probably need to define a class for `generic_connection_variable` so it has a method called `someApplicableMethod()`.

Comment: Add 'self' in the method definition line (and preferably show the class definition too) if you are accessing 'instance'. What is self in your code?